# Using Spongycastle with Proguard

Tags: android, adt, proguard, spongycastle

I've been strugling with proguard to make Spongycastle work.
Most of the time, the problem comes when I'm exporting a signed APK, either I've got error, or the app will just crash before starting.

So, I've managed to gather informations to get a working proguard configuration :

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic

-libraryjars C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
-libraryjars libs\sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar
-libraryjars libs\scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar

-injars libs

-outjars bin/classes-processed.jar

-dontwarn javax.naming.**
-dontwarn android.support.**


####
-keep class org.**  { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

I'm running **ADT Version: 22.0.0.v201305140200--675183**
The test phone is **under Android 2.3.5**

The part that borrows me is the "`-keep class org.**  { *; }`" .... Am I doing it right ? I've tried "`-keep class org.spongycastle.**  { *; }`", but the **app just crash before startup...**

Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

We added

```
-keep class org.spongycastle.**
-dontwarn org.spongycastle.jce.provider.X509LDAPCertStoreSpi
-dontwarn org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper
```

But we now run into the problem that we hit the DEX method limit of 2^16 with that lib.
We only need it for the MD5 and SHA-1 algorithms as some phones don't ship those.

Comment: maybe you found more lightweight (with less methods) library than spongycastle?

Comment: I've also hit the DEX method limit when using spongy castle. To make it work I added: multiDexEnabled true, to the build.gradle file. I've been using the following proguard rules: https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/blob/master/proguard-spongycastle.pro, but also had crashes. Not being able to resolve them and to end my misery, I've just added: -keep class org.spongycastle.* {*;}. I don't have problems when using it like this, but it doesn't seem like the proper way to go. Any suggestions?

Comment: same problem here, fixed with the solution above.